# How to add a step to remove a column with constant value?

Tags: r, machine-learning, time-series, tidymodels, r-recipes

**Background:** I'm creating a recipe to clean and transform time-series data that will be used by multiple models. One of the steps in the recipe is to remove correlated predictors using the `step_corr()` function.

However, due to the nature of the data set, some of the variables can have a constant value for the entire set of training data when doing cross-validation using a rolling window and thus cause the `step_corr()` function to throw a warning.

**Problem Statement**: In such cases, is it possible to exclude such variables from the correlation step? Or perhaps remove the variable entirely?

P.S. I know I can easily ignore the warning and proceed. But I'm looking for a cleaner approach / best practice advice.

Comment: You're looking for `step_nzv` near zero variance.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! @phiver

Comment: @phiver, while it's short, I think that should be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two steps for you to consider:

- [`step_zv()`](https://recipes.tidymodels.org/reference/step_zv.html) will remove variables that all have the same value (zero variance)
- [`step_nzv()`](https://recipes.tidymodels.org/reference/step_nzv.html) will remove variables that *almost* all have the same value (highly sparse and unbalanced)

Comment: `step_zv()` is better as I'm dealing with dummy variables. Thanks, @Julia Silge